# How to align CAD drawings?

Tags: snapping

I'm really fighting with Blender's Snap controls - compared to CAD packages I've used, they're hugely frustrating.

I'm trying to overlay two floor plans. I've managed to align them on the Y axis, but can't seem to find a combo of snap settings that align on the X - it seems to jump to some random location. It's obviously picking some other point as the snap source.

Is there a simple way to say "Take this point on this drawing, and move it to this point on this drawing?" It's a 2-second job in other packages, but it's taken me 20 minutes of fighting to even get this far in Blender!

Failing that, is there a recommended Addon that brings in some CAD controls?

[image: Overlaid plans]

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I seem to have found some sort of method for doing it. Move it close, snap the 3D cursor to the 'from' point, set the origin to the 3D cursor, move it again to the 'to' point. Really convoluted, but seems to do the job.